# Any Bluedroid test or sample code?

Tags: android, c, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

The only sample/test code in C for the bluedroid API layer in android is the bluedroidtest program which is not very illustrative.  I want to use some features of the hci interface (that's redundant, I know), and it would be nifty if there were some guidelines to use.  I look at the BlueZ module for Linux and there's tons of stuff to go by.  I figure that with the resources of Google and Broadcom, there must be something to go by, but I can't find much in the AOSP file tree.

Comment: Go through this source code https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth.html

Comment: external/bluetooth/hci  This directory in the project will have example code

Comment: If you are finding this then let me know I will post this as answer

Comment: In my repo copy of external, I have some C source code in external/bluetooth/bluedroid/hci/src, but it looks like the implementation of a library and not using it.  I will have to read more.  Thanks for the pointer.  For example, there's a file bt_hci_bdroid.c which has the description: Description:   Bluedroid Bluetooth Host/Controller interface library implementation.  So, this may be the best that there is.  Post it as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Someone downvote the answer .Can you please accept the answer as soon as possible ?

Comment: Thanks once again . i do not know what was problem with my answer . you can edit the answer anytime i do not mind :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth.html Go through this link.
And In source code you should read external/bluetooth/hci.
Hope you get it. Best of luck..!

Comment: I have asked to questioner that if this link is useful than and than only I will post you can read the comment whoever down vote this post

Comment: You can give comment if you don't mind

Comment: In my repo copy of external, I have some C source code in external/bluetooth/bluedroid/hci/src, but there's no source code on the Android Bluetooth page.  This is a good starting point though.